# C# removal of items in a list by string

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# and one of the problems i'm having is the search of an item in my list by string. It keeps giving errors and I don't known how to fix this. I've been searching the internet and haven't found a working solution. It is probably me misunderstanding the answers and i'm hoping I can get a solution this way.

```
 bl = bn.Vind("JA");
 Test(bl.Count == 2, "2 bezettingen voor passagier met tekst 'JA' in zijn naam.");



    public List<Bezetting> Vind(string v)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (_items.Contains(v)) -- Argument1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'ClassLibrary.Bezettingen'
                return _items;
        }
    }        
}
```

Hope this can set me on my way for the rest.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What errors?  What is `_items`?

Comment: What are you doing exactly? you want to search within the list? using a keyword string? and return the List based on that keyword?

Comment: _items is a list and the search is coming from a string. After the search it should give all the results of the elements that are in the list containing the search string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what are you doing inside that method of yours, it is very confusing, but since you made an effort i'm going to give you a solution.

for searching a string within a List you may want to approach this way:

```
public List<YourModel> Search(string keyword)
{
  //here you should populate your list from database or wherever! for now im just initializing it.  
  List<YourModel> myList = new List<YourModel>();
  //you can have inside validation as well e.g:
  if(myList.Any(x=> x.Contains(keyword)))
  {
    //if you simply want to get First Set of Data
    //return myList.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Contains(keyword));
    return myList.Where(x=> x.Contains(keyword)).ToList();
  }
  else
    return myList; 
}
```

Comment: `return myList.Any(x=> x.Contains("keyword")).ToList();` is invalid.  `.Any()` returns `bool`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! I know it isn't easy because of the short parts i gave but I thought giving more would be too much.
I'm still getting the error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'YourModel' because it is not a delegate type.

Comment: Yeah it really needs to be something like `.Where(x=>x.YourProp.Contains(keyword))` as `x` would be of type `YourModel` and not `string`

Comment: @Clint `YourModel` is the class that you have the properties within it. if you do not have properties make sure u create a class and define your properties.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at the `.Contains(...)` on the `List<>` object.  This will try to compare the value of `v` with the items withing the list.  If the list is not strings this will not work.  If they are strings it will compare the entire item and not within the item.

You want something like this instead... (first match)

```
return _items.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.YourProperty.Contains(v));
```

... or this ... (all matches match)

```
return _items.Where(i=>i.YourProperty.Contains(v)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, got me a decent step closer. Still getting errors but i keep looking for the solution.

Comment: compiler errors or exceptions?  Show the declation for `_items` and the definition for `Bezetting`